# Looping through all divs inside a container div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to do a sort of invoicing system, and the html looks like this:

```html
<invoice>
  <headers>
    <div date contenteditable>15-Jan-2020</div>
    <div buyer contenteditable>McDonalds</div>
    <div order contenteditable>145632</div>
  </headers>
  <item>
    <div name contenteditable>Big Mac</div>
    <div quantity contenteditable>5</div>
    <div rate contenteditable>20.00</div>
  </item>
  <item>
    <div name contenteditable>Small Mac</div>
    <div quantity contenteditable>10</div>
    <div rate contenteditable>10.00</div>
  </item>
</invoice>

<button>Loop</button>
```

I need to loop through each `<invoice>` and get details from `<headers>` and `<item>`, so the end results look like this.

```
date : 15-Jan-2020 buyer : McDonalds order:145632
item : Big Mac quantity : 5 rate : 20.00
item : Small Mac quantity : 10 rate : 10.00
```

I plan on sending this data as json to a PHP script for processing.

The problem is, `<headers>`,`<items>` wont be the only containers in each invoice. There could be `<address>`,`<transporter>` etc. but they'll all be inside each `<invoice>`.

With that being the case, how can I loop through each container and get it's data?

Here's the jQuery I was attempting:

```
var button = $("button")

button.on("click", function() {
  $('invoice').each(function() {
    alert('It works');

  });
});
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/31wsrbh4/1/)

Comment: I do not think if `invoice` is a valid HTML tag.

Comment: Does the attribute not need to say `contenteditable="true"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through `div` and use `data-attribute` for name label as below

```js
$('invoice>headers>div, invoice>item>div').each(function(index,item) {

  console.log($(this).attr('data-name'),  $(this).text());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<invoice>
  <headers>
    <div date contenteditable data-name="date">15-Jan-2020</div>
    <div buyer contenteditable  data-name="buyer">McDonalds</div>
    <div order contenteditable  data-name="order">145632</div>
  </headers>
  <item>
    <div name contenteditable data-name="name">Big Mac</div>
    <div quantity contenteditable data-name="quantity">5</div>
    <div rate contenteditable data-name="rate">20.00</div>
  </item>
  <item>
    <div name contenteditable data-name="name">Small Mac</div>
    <div quantity contenteditable data-name="quantity">10</div>
    <div rate contenteditable data-name="rate">10.00</div>
  </item>
</invoice>
```

Comment: Looks good, but can we restrict it to `div`s only inside the `invoice` containers. There'll be several other `div`s on the page, so I assume it'll go searching through all of them.

Comment: Any idea how I could get the name of the container Eg: headers or items?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('headers > div, item > div').each(function(item) {
  console.log('item');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems your HTML isn't valid HTML. The spec doesn't define elements like `<invoice>`, `<headers>` and `<item>`. Besides that, attributes on elements almost always resemble key-value pairs, meaning you should declare your `name`, `buyer`, `order`, `quantity` and `rate` attributes as values of existing attributes. The `contenteditable` attribute is a boolean attribute which is OK to be left as it currently is.

Here is a fixed and working example:

```js
var button = $('#read-invoice');

// readLine :: [String] -> (HTMLElement -> String)
function readLine(fields) {
  return function (el) {
    return fields.reduce(function (txt, field) {
      var data = $('.' + field, el).text();
      return txt === ''
        ? field + ': ' + data
        : txt + '; ' + field + ': ' + data
    }, '');
  }
}

// readBlock :: { (HTMLElement -> String) } -> (HTMLElement -> String)
function readBlock(readers) {
  return function (el) {
    var rtype = el.className;
    if (typeof readers[rtype] === 'function') {
      return readers[rtype](el);
    }
    return '';
  }
}

// autoRead :: HTMLElement -> String
var autoRead = readBlock({
  headers: readLine(['date', 'buyer', 'order']),
  item: readLine(['name', 'quantity', 'rate'])
  // ... address, etc.
});

button.on('click', function () {
  var result = $('.invoice').
    children().
    toArray().
    reduce(function (txt, el) {
      var line = autoRead(el);
      return line === ''
        ? txt
        : txt + line + '\n';
    }, '');
    
  console.log(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="invoice">
  <div class="headers">
    <div class="date" contenteditable>15-Jan-2020</div>
    <div class="buyer" contenteditable>McDonalds</div>
    <div class="order" contenteditable>145632</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="name" contenteditable>Big Mac</div>
    <div class="quantity" contenteditable>5</div>
    <div class="rate" contenteditable>20.00</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="name" contenteditable>Small Mac</div>
    <div class="quantity" contenteditable>10</div>
    <div class="rate" contenteditable>10.00</div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="read-invoice">Loop</button>
```

**JS explanation**

The function `readLine` takes an `Array` of `String`s, where each `String` resembles the class name of one of the inner `<div>` elements. It returns a function that's waiting for a "block" element (like `<div class="headers">`) and reads the contents of it's contained `<div>`'s into a single `String`. Let's call the returned function a *reader*.

The `readBlock` function takes an `Object` of reader functions and returns a function taking a "block" element. The returned function determines which type of "block" it received and calls the matching reader function with the element as argument. If no reader matches the block type, it returns the empty `String`.

In the end, `autoRead` becomes a single function taking in a whole "block" element and returning all of it's contents as a line of text.

The `button` click handler looks up the `<div class="invoice">` element, traverses it's DOM tree down to it's child elements (our "block" elements) and passes each "block" to `autoRead`, building up a result `String`. The final result is logged to the console.

**Extending**

To add new types of "block"s, simply define a new reader for it and add it to the `Object` passed to `readBlock`. For example, to add an `<div class="address">` reader that reads "name", "street", "zip" and "city" infos:

```
var autoRead = readBlock({
  headers: readLine(['date', 'buyer', 'order']),
  item: readLine(['name', 'quantity', 'rate']),
  address: readLine(['name', 'street', 'zip', 'city']) // <<< new
});
```

Extending the fields a certain reader reads is also simple, just add the name of the field to read:

```
var autoRead = readBlock({
  headers: readLine(['date', 'buyer', 'order']),
  item: readLine(['name', 'quantity', 'rate', 'currency']) // <<< added "currency"
});
```